# HTML5 + JS goto next video function not activating

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am trying to get offline videos to play on a DIY web app. I can load in multiple videos, but when I click the button to switch to the next video, it doesn't do so.

HTML:

```
<input id="newlocalFILE" name="localfile" size="50" maxlength="100000" accept="video/*" type="file" onchange="playlocalVID();"  multiple="multiple">
<button title = "next video" onclick="nextvid()">next vid</button>
<video class = "neutral" autoplay controls id="videoPlayer">
<source id="currentVID" src="optimote.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
function nextvid() {
    var player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    var currentVID = document.getElementById("currentVID");
    var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById("newlocalFILE").files[1];
    currentVID.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(selectedLocalVID));
    player.load();
    player.play();
    // var i = 0; //needs to be outside while loop?
    // if (i >= name.length) {
    //     alert('reached end of playlist!');
    //     return;
    // }
    document.getElementByTagName("video").src = vids[i];
    i++;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is this line:

```
    var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById("newlocalFILE").files[1];
```

You hard-coded the index of video list to `1`, so whatever you do, the video still play at the second file

You should define a global variable outside the scope, and increase the index each time clicking next button. This is my solution. Let's run the code to see the result

PS: I refresh the index to `0` when it is end of the the playlist.

```js
let currentVideoIndex = 0;

function playVideo(file) {
   const player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
   currentVID.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
   player.load();
   player.play();
}

function nextvid() {
   const currentVID = document.getElementById("currentVID");
   const selectedFiles = document.getElementById("newlocalFILE");
   currentVideoIndex = currentVideoIndex >= selectedFiles.files.length - 1 
     ? 0 : currentVideoIndex + 1;
     
   const selectedLocalVID = selectedFiles.files[currentVideoIndex];
   playVideo(selectedLocalVID);
}

function playlocalVID() {
  const selectedFiles = document.getElementById("newlocalFILE");
  currentVideoIndex = 0;
  if (selectedFiles.files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const src = selectedFiles.files[0];
  playVideo(src);
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="newlocalFILE" name="localfile" size="50" maxlength="100000" accept="video/*" type="file" onchange="playlocalVID();"  multiple="multiple">
    <button title = "next video" onclick="nextvid()">next vid</button>
    <video class = "neutral" autoplay controls id="videoPlayer">
    <source id="currentVID" src="optimote.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason on windows when I select multiple files it always plays clipA first then ClipB when next button is clicked, even if I select ClipB first. Is there any way to fix this in the code so that windows file picker allows specified order of clips? It also must not play the first clip all over again if next has been clicked too many times.

Comment: It depends on file input, and of course it will be sorted by windows. If you want to add in by time order, you just allow open 1 file once, then add each file into global array variable. Second, because you don't have `back` button, so I play the list in loop. If the index is out of range, it will go back to first video. You can change it too

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have your video index somewhere globally, outside the function, because otherwise when you click on next video, the `i` is reseted all the time to `0`, that means it takes only the first one.

So basically you should have something like this:

```
let currentVideoIndex = 0;
function nextvid() {
    var player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    var currentVID = document.getElementById("currentVID");
    var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById("newlocalFILE").files[1];
    currentVID.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(selectedLocalVID));
    player.load();
    player.play();
    if (currentVideoIndex >= name.length) {
         alert('reached end of playlist!');
         return;
    }
    document.getElementByTagName("video").src = vids[i];
    currentVideoIndex++;
}
```

Note: I didn't tested, since I don't have the whole logic for import... but I guess you get the idea.